# Remove lines containing specific strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function to remove all lines containing specific strings in Python text files and while I'm able to write a function, it doesn't do what I want. When I open my file and read the lines, it either gives me the original file or no lines at all.

Here are a couple alternatives I tried:

```
bads = ['IV\t', '', 'Speaker Key:\n', 'Page 1 of 1\n']
string_bads = str(bads)

def prepText(file):
    with open(file, 'w+') as textfile:
        for line in textfile: 
            if not string_bads in line:
                pass
            else:
                textfile.write(line)   


def prepText(file):
    with open(file, 'w+') as textfile:
        for line in textfile: 
            if not string_bads in line:
                pass
            else:
                textfile.write(line)

def prepText(file):
    with open(file, 'w') as textfile:
        for line in textfile:
            if line.strip("\n") != string_bads:
               textfile.write(line)

def prepText(file1, file2):
     with open(file1) as oldfile, open(file2, 'w') as newfile:
         for line in oldfile:
             if not any(string_bads in line for bads in string_bads):
               newfile.write(line)
```

afterwards, I just pass the file(s) to the function and once that's done, I do this:

```
with open("newfile") as good_one:
    lines = good_one.readlines()
print(lines)
lines
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of your input and desired output

Comment: You're reading a line from the file, then (sometimes) writing a new line directly after that point. That will not replace a line, but mess up the file.

Comment: `string_bads` is bad. You should not use it. Use `bads` instead.

Comment: The last version would work (read one file, write to another), but your `string_bads` variable is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

You have a big problem here:

```py
bads = ['IV\t', '', 'Speaker Key:\n', 'Page 1 of 1\n']
string_bads = str(bads)
```

because your `string_bads` will be:

```py
"['IV\\t', '', 'Speaker Key:\\n', 'Page 1 of 1\\n']"
```

If you want to check for each line in a file if it contains **one or more** of the strings in `bads` this should look like this:

```py
def prepText(file1, file2):
     with open(file1) as oldfile, open(file2, 'w') as newfile:
         for line in oldfile:
             if not any(bad in line for bad in bads):
               newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: The last 5 lines can also be written like the last 2 lines in the last example in the question (using `any`), all that was needed was to replace `bads`/`string_bads` by `bad`/`bads`.